# C# WFA to install Bulk .apk files

Tags: c#, batch-file

I am working on a project, firing adb commands via C# application and i am almost done all the
thing i want it to do but i am having problem with installing applications in bulk via adb command.

I tried the following Code:-

```
    private void Select_Multiple_Apps_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Select your APK..";
        openFileDialog1.FileName = "Choose File..";
        openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
        openFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = true;
        openFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;
        openFileDialog1.Filter = " .APK|*.apk";

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            TXT_BLK_INSTL.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;   
        }   
    }

    private void Install_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /*Process Bulk_Install = Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/c FOR %%n in (*.apk) DO adb install "%%n");
        Bulk_Install.WaitForExit();
        MessageBox.Show(".APK is Installed", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);*/
    }
```

But its not allowing me to use the batch script code, is there any other way i can do bulk install of applications (Path given by user)?

Thanks!

Comment: please be a bit more specific - what is "not allowing me to use batch script code"? any error message there?

Comment: When i put this line "/c FOR %%n in (*.apk) DO adb install "%%n" it show error in the line and i can't run the app,

Comment: The actual error may be of some significance.

Comment: Now i am using that line in a batch script and calling that batch script via my C# WFA and its getting me the job done of installing all the apk files in directory but i want to integrate something like that into my C# WFA and don't want to call a batch script!

YES YOU CAN CALL ME A REAL NOOB! :(

Comment: what's wrong with just using `c#` to iterate through the list of packages and install them one by one? this way you will have more control over the whole process, handle errors more easily, even be able to display a nice progress bar if you would want to.

Comment: I was also thinking of adding the proress bar but i don't know how do i measure the the progress of ADB, do you have any idea?

It will be great if i can add a progress bar, i will be able to hide the CMD window and show only progress bar! :D

Answer (score 0):

The command needs to be `Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/c FOR %n in (*.apk) DO adb install \"%n\"");`

Microsoft wants `%%<variable>` to be used inside scripts and `%<variable>` used in command line

Comment: I still getting error, "Too many characters in character Literals"

Comment: No Overload for method START takes 3 Arguments!